# The model resource: (project_id, model_name) was not found

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have the deployed ml model in my GCP project and I am trying to get online prediction in google-cloud-functions . But when I call my function model_run() , I see error in logs : The model resource: (project_id, model_name) was not found . How can I fix it ?

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

def model_run(project = PROJECT_ID, model = MODEL_NAME, instances = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]], version=None):

    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
    name = 'projects/{}/models/{}'.format(project, model)

    if version is not None:
        name += '/versions/{}'.format(version)

    response = service.projects().predict(
        name=name,
        body={'instances': instances}
    ).execute()

    if 'error' in response:
        raise RuntimeError(response['error'])

    return response['predictions']

model_run()
```

Comment: 1) How did you set up default authorization for the SDK? Try running **gcloud auth application-default login** and then try again. 2) Your code is a copy of the Google example. Double-check that you have the PROJECT_ID (not project name) and MODEL  specified correctly.

Comment: What service did you use to deploy your model (eg. AI platform, Vertex AI)?

Comment: @RiccoD I used AI platform

Comment: @JohnHanley can I send you a loom-video with a detailed description of the problem ?